# Bootstrap onclick event using glyphicon possible?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to use onclick event? For example

```
<a href="#menu4" onclick="a()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
```

JQuery

```
function a(){
alert("HI!");
$("#menu4").tabs({ active: # });
}
```

How do you call this function with glyphicon?

Comment: yes possible.this should work.what error you are getting?

Comment: I think its not calling the function a because Hi is not alerting

Comment: you have to do `href="javascript:;" ` then it will work.

Comment: yeah I already did, but still doesn't work

Comment: can you insert snippet of your code

Answer (score 1):

Link to with onclick should have `href="javascript:;"`

```js
    function a(){
    alert("HI!");
    //$("#menu4").tabs({ active: # });
    }
```